# Problem in Shapefiles

Tags: maps, shapefile, geo, geotools

i need a help
i have a shape file that continue 3716 polygon record and want to draw this shape file where some of those polygons need to have a specified color

OR WANT a search technique to search this map for a point (lat-long) and get it's belong polygon but not by searching all polygons

i tries all, OpenJump-Source code, GeoTools,....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GeoTools you can follow the [Style tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/examples/stylelab.html) to show you how to display your shapefile. There is no way to carry out a point in polygon search without at least examining the bounding box of each polygon but the GeoTools [Query Lab](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/examples/querylab.html) will talk you through the basics of setting up a query (and if your shapefile has a spatial index then it will be quick enough).

Comment: i think the Styles can give me limited editing, i need to make each polygon in the shape file (exactly about 3617 polygon) have it's unique color, i think styles can't make that, Right ?????????

i will try now the query Lab, hope it work

Comment: You will just need 3617 different rules - there probably isn't an easier way unless the colors are encoded in the attributes. I'm pretty sure that no one will be able to distinguish between that many colours.